# Information about shared faces in tetrahedral mesh

Tags: 3d, mesh

i have a big problem with tetrahedral mesh...
I want to create a a tetrahedral mesh (3-D) for a finite volume time domain code, giving as input two files (*.node and *.ele).

The format of *.node is:
First line: <# of points>  <# of attributes> <# of boundary markers (0 or 1)>
Remaining lines list # of points:
        [attributes] [boundary marker]
    ...

The format of *.ele is:
First line: <# of tetrahedra>  <# of attributes>
Remaining lines list of # of tetrahedra:
         ... [attributes]
    ...

From these 2 files, the Mesh class that i have developed, creates the Faces of each Tetrahedron (starting from the nodes IDs) and then create the Element Tetrahedron using the information of 4 nodes and 4 faces.
The problem is that, with only these files, i don't have the information of the shared faces of each element, and so i have to do checks within the face list, in order to eliminate the doubles.
This procedure takes a lot of time..
Does anybody knows a more intelligent method to overcome my problem?

P.s: i can also generate file .*face and file *.neigh: the first lists all the faces (not considering the doubles) and the corresponding nodes, the second gives me information about the neighbour element of each tetraedron in terms of elements id (not in terms of shared id faces.)

The format of *.face is:
    First line: <# of faces> 
    Remaining lines list of # of faces:
        [boundary marker]
    ...

The format of *.neigh is:
    First line: <# of tetrahedra> <# of nei. per tet (always 4) >
    Remaining lines list of # of neighbors:
        
    ...

My problem is that my procedure takes a lot of time to identify the shared faces and delete them... I was asking if there was a more intelligent way to do that (maybe using particular data structure or other methods) with the information that i can generate (.node, .ele, .face, .neigh)

Thanks:)

Comment: I could'nt find the line which mention your specific problem.

Comment: My problem is that my procedure takes a lot of time to identify the shared faces and delete them...
I was asking if there was a more intelligent way to do that (maybe using particular data structure or other methods) with the information that i can generate (.node, .ele, .face, .neigh)

Comment: Would you be kind enough to add that piece of information to the question bye *editing* it?

Comment: Yes no problem! Done. It's ok now?